# Internationalization (i18n) Routing gives me 404 error

Tags: next.js

I'm trying to use next to lead with multiple languages on my website.

i made some configuration on next.config.js

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {}

module.exports = nextConfig

module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ["en-US", "pt-BR", "es"],
    defaultLocale: "en-US",
  },
}
```

I created a pages/language folder and inside a folder for each language (example pt-BR, en-US) then an index.tsx with the following configuration:

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Bem-vindo ao meu site!</h1>
      {/* ... */}
    </div>
  )
}
```

But I get standard nextjs error page

I tried a few things but nothing worked

Answer (score 0):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/53724) with Next.js at the moment. The solution is to remove the i18n key from your `next.config.js` completely when using the app directory.

If you need additional resources on how to internationalize your app with Next.js, I have created some resources myself:

- Check out my [example repository](https://github.com/fabio-nettis/nextjs13-appdir-i18n)
- Check out the accompanying [medium article](https://medium.com/stackademic/the-ultimate-guide-to-internationalization-with-next-js-13-eb1be3d1a9e2).

Comment: @LucianoClecio Happy to help. If you think the answer is useful, think about marking it as accepted answer.